# Polynomials- Prove that function can be only polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

> Suppose there exist a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\cdot f'(x)$ is polynomial It. is trivial that if $f(x)$ is polynomial, then $f(x)\cdot f'(x)$ is polynomial.

My question is: how would one prove that $f(x)$ can be only polynomial?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not true in general that $f$ must be a polynomial, take for example $\,f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}\,$. What *is* true, however, is that $f^2$ must be a polynomial. Hint: $f \cdot f' = \frac{1}{2}\left(f^2\right)'$.

Comment: however if we add that f(x)^3 is polynomial too ie  f'(x)^3 is polynomial =>3f(x)^2*f'(x) is polynomial can we conclude the  above

Comment: @ArmanDavtyan The first condition is enough to prove that $\,f(x)=\pm \sqrt{P(x)}\,$ for some polynomial $P$. If you add a second condition that $f^3$ is also a polynomial then, yes, it follows that $P$ must be a perfect square, so $f$ is a polynomial.